# Android navigation drawer does not fill the actionbar space

Tags: android, listview, android-studio, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer

I am developing an application that uses the side navigation drawer. I had tried to make the navigation drawer slide with the action bar goes to the right and i done. However, when the action bar goes to the right, the ListView in the navigation drawer did not fill up the space. It just leave an empty blank grey space. Please help.

Below was my code:

myActivity.xml:

```
   <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    tools:context=".currentJob"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="16dp"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="1">

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Random Text"
            android:id="@+id/lbl_title"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_20sdp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <ListView

        android:id="@+id/navList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left|start"
        android:background="#ffeeeeee"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

MyActivity.java

```
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_current_job);

        //setup list header
        listHeaderView = View.inflate(this,R.layout.menuheaderview, null);

        //setup drawer
        mDrawerList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.navList);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        double width=(getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels/100.00)*75;    //drawer layout width in percentage

        int w = (int)width;

        DrawerLayout.LayoutParams params =                     (android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.LayoutParams) mDrawerList.getLayoutParams();
        params.width = w;

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.icon_drawer);

        mDrawerList.setLayoutParams(params);
        addDrawerItems();
        setupDrawer();
    }
```

addDrawerItems function

```
private void addDrawerItems() {

    //add items operations
    mAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter(menu,this);
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()          {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(myActivity.this, "You selected ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

setupDrawer function

```
private void setupDrawer() {
mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
        R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {

    /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
    public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {

        invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
    }

    /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
    public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {

        invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
        super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, slideOffset);

        float xPositionOpenDrawer = mDrawerList.getWidth();
        float xPositionWindowContent = (slideOffset * xPositionOpenDrawer);
        getActionBarView().setX(xPositionWindowContent);
    }
};
mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
mDrawerToggle.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.icon_drawer);
mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
}
```

getActionBarView function

```
public View getActionBarView() {

    Window window = this.getWindow();
    final View decorView = window.getDecorView();
    final String packageName =  getPackageName();
    final int resId =        this.getResources().getIdentifier("action_bar_container", "id", packageName);
    final View actionBarView = decorView.findViewById(resId);
    return actionBarView;
}
```

Please help me I really tried my best but still can't find any solutions.

[image: NavigationDrawerProblem]

Comment: can you attach screen shot?

Comment: i have attached my screenshot. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Try adding `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` in your `android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout`.

Comment: Just tried. Doesn't work. Btw thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

If you want that  effect, consider use of Toolbar instead of ActionBar. Use toolbar object support as Action bar. It provide a flexibility to place toolbar anywhere in layout file, just like any other view in layout.